# Creating a large number of random serial keys

Tags: algorithm, random, license-key, serial-number

I am developing a application where user is only authenticated if he enters a serial key correctly. This serial key is matched with the serial key already present in database. This serial key should consists of 6 digit and 3 alphabets. Users get these key in written form from me.

How do I generate a large number (100,000,000 approx) of serial keys?

Comment: How do the users get the keys?

Comment: they get in written form

Comment: How high "security" do you need on the keys? Assuming no checksum, an attacker would have to generate ~176 keys on average to guess one correctly. Good enough?

Comment: i need it with high security with checksum.

Comment: adding a checksum will make it less secure (fewer keys to try)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way in my opinion is:

1. find a desired number in range `[1,10000000)`, let it be `x` and it
   will represent your 6 digits.
2. Find 3 characters (let's assume in range a-z). Let them be `a,b,c`.
3. Your number is `(a-'a' + b-'a'*26 + c-'a'*26*26)*10000000 + x`

(Where 'a' is the ascii representation of the character `'a'`, and a-'a' means the numeric ascii subtraction)

Note that the generated number can even fit in a `long` - assuming it is 64 bits.

---

Generation of several numbers can be simply done with iteration, start with `a=b=c='a'`, and `x=0`, and start advancing (increase by 1). Once you reached `x=10000000`, increase a, if `a` passed z - increase `b`, .... (similar to what you would do in normal integer addition arithmetic).

Comment: is it random? it looks like kind of sequential which is easy to predict.

Comment: @GaganDeep: No, it is sequential (I did not understand you are after random). To get random one can iteratively create different values for x,a,b,c and maintain a set to check if these values are still available.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a secure random number generator like `SecureRandom` to generate the keys.

But as already mentioned in a comment, if you generate that many keys, the space of all possible keys is not much larger. So it will be easy for an attacker to try out keys until one is found that works.

Comment: so what is the solution for that?

Comment: With the SecureRandom you can generate enough random bytes that you can convert to a key that looks like you described it. For example like amit has described it in his answer. If you need higher security, make the key longer.